# max-flow min_cut flow network

Tags: max-flow

I read about the flow network problem 1 week ago , and there is a problem that i feel so confused : max-flow min-cut problem . I have searched about it , in wiki , geeksforgeeks , ... But i still don't understand it clearly .

In some article about min-cut in flow network , i often see : all edges which are from the reachable vertex to a non-reachable vertex are minimum cut edges . I know the reachable vertex is vertex that have been reached from the source vertex S by using residual graph , but i wonder why we choose all this edges .

Can someone explain about it for me ?  Thank you so much.

Comment: You're looking for "Ford-Fulkerson algorithm" and a proof of its correctness. That question may be more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms . Note that StackOverflow/StackExchange is generally not a discussion forum and may be not suitable for general "explain it to me" questions; it's more about you having a specific question about a specific step in a specific proof that you can quote.

Comment: oh , thank you so much !